# How to subtract date in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try make list from curent date until last 31 days. I try use `ng-repeat` to make list today until 31 day. I can make list but not date. I try code like this

**HTML**

```
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="i in rep">
                    {{trip}}
                    {{besok}}
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.rep = [];
for (var i=0; i < 31; i++) {  
   $scope.trip = new Date();
   $scope.besok = $scope.trip.setDate($scope.trip.getDate()- i);
   $scope.rep.push(i);
}
```

[image]

and it will show like this. It cannot subtract day. How to reduce it properly in angularjs ? please help me solved this problem. Thanks

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: what you are doing is just fine. But you gotta push your updated date in your array. How else would you be able to display it using the `ng-repeat`?

Comment: i want show list date from curent date until "curent date - i" i just want simple like this but i fail make it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this. i know this is not angularjs code. same logic would work in both

```js
var rep = [];
for (var i=0; i < 31; i++) {  
   var trip = new Date();
   
   var besok =new Date(trip.getTime() - i*(24*60*60*1000));
   rep.push(besok);
}
console.log(rep);
```

Comment: It not what i want, i want make list from curent date unti curent date -i. example firs list 2017-06-14, second list 2017-06-13, third list 2017-06-12 until end of i.

Comment: Not format what i want just in make list from curent date until 31 day before

Comment: Yes it right to subtract date thank bro, i just make ng-repeat to make list date. because with your code one list show data until end not desc. But really big thank from your help it save my day

Comment: Glad. it helped. thanks for accepting answer @RizkaNugroho